# Why doesn't strip(",") method won't turn comma separated string into list in python?

Tags: python, string, list, strip

I have a file (`my_file`) containing two lines:

```
"002000", "WAYNE", "ROONEY", "M", 16SEP2012, 31DEC1977, 25OCT1968, 999999, "UK", "380", VOID;
"002001", "JOE", "COLE", "M", 16SEP2012, 31DEC1977, 13FEB1972, 999999, "UK", "390", VOID;
```

I do:

```
f = open(my_file)
lines = [line.strip() for line in f]
f.close()

for line in lines:
    print line
    print type(line)

print "------------------"
for line in lines:
    print line.strip(",")
    print type(line.strip(","))
```

In the output:

```
"002000", "WAYNE", "ROONEY", "M", 16SEP2012, 31DEC1977, 25OCT1968, 999999, "UK", "380", VOID;
<type 'str'>
"002001", "JOE", "COLE", "M", 16SEP2012, 31DEC1977, 13FEB1972, 999999, "UK", "390", VOID;
<type 'str'>
------------------
"002000", "WAYNE", "ROONEY", "M", 16SEP2012, 31DEC1977, 25OCT1968, 999999, "UK", "380", VOID;
<type 'str'>
"002001", "JOE", "COLE", "M", 16SEP2012, 31DEC1977, 13FEB1972, 999999, "UK", "390", VOID;
<type 'str'>
```

I excpect `list` objects in 2nd for loop, because i use `strip(",")` method on each line, but it still returns `<type 'str'>`. What is wrong?

Comment: You have failed to read the documentation.

Answer (score 6):

[`str.strip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#str.strip) remove surround character:

```
>>> ',,a,b,,'.strip(',')
'a,b'
```

Use [`str.split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#str.split) to get list:

```
>>> 'a,b,c'.split(',')
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

---

```
>>> line = '"002000", "WAYNE", "ROONEY", "M", 16SEP2012, 31DEC1977, 25OCT1968, 999999, "UK", "380", VOID;"'
>>> [x.strip('" ') for x in line.split(',')]
['002000', 'WAYNE', 'ROONEY', 'M', '16SEP2012', '31DEC1977', '25OCT1968', '999999', 'UK', '380', 'VOID;']
```

Comment: It should also turn each comma separated line string into a list

Comment: @alwbtc: And so it does!

Comment: right, i should use split.

Comment: ok, after using split, it returns `['"002000"', ' "WAYNE"', ' "ROONEY"', ' "M"', ' 16SEP2012', ' 31DEC1977', ' 25OCT1968', ' 999999', ' "UK"', ' "380"', ' VOID;']` but i want `["002000", "WAYNE", "ROONEY", "M", "16SEP2012", "31DEC1977", "25OCT1968", "999999", "UK", "380", "VOID;"]`

Comment: @alwbtc, Try `line.split(', ')` or `map(str.strip, line.split(','))`.

Comment: how about the extra double quotes?

Comment: thanks. i feel me bad not making effort myself, though